# Animating a "peek" effect with CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a "peek" effect with only CSS animations.

What I mean by that is that There will be a little blurb of content in a square, with a more detailed description underneath. When the user hovers over the square, the new content slides up from the bottom and fills in as much space as it contains.

I have a JavaScript solution that uses mouseenter and mouseleave to calculate the correct position of top based on the heights of the things that area already visible, and have a css animation on that, but I'm trying to figure out a way to do it using only CSS.

My attempt so far is this: http://jsfiddle.net/7yrWL/1/

This uses a technique like this:

```
.peek { max-height: 0; transition: max-height 1s; }
.main:hover .peek { max-height: 300px; } /* I'd prefer if this were auto or 100% */
```

When you hover over main, the max-height changes and it pushes the peek content into view.

However, my problem is that since I have to use a static px value for max-height in order for the css transition to work, the animation looks like it takes a different amount of time to complete depending on how large the peek text is. It also has a noticeable delay when you hover off of it as the max-height transition "catches up" to the real height.

Anyone know any alternate ways to do this (not using JavaScript)?

Comment: Well, firstly I can tell you that this is impossible using auto or 100% height.  CSS3 transitions simply doesn't understand how to apply a transition to height: auto; at the moment, and percentage heights are a particularly abstract thing to deal with in the first place.  Without setting html to 100% height before hand this won't work either.  Unfortunately there is truly not a good way of doing this other than doing it with javascript.  It's a limitation all of us face.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is really tricky, the key is to use translation and take care about the titles height:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/vzvXf/17/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="peeks">
    <li>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <h4>Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="peek">
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <h4>Subtitle</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="peek">
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                    <p>Test peek test peek<br/>Test peek</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.peeks {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.peeks:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

ul.peeks > li {
    width: 300px;
    border: 10px solid orange;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.peeks > li.large {
    width: 600px;
}

ul.peeks > li > div {
    padding: 75px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

ul.peeks > li > div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

ul.peeks > li > div > div {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s
}

ul.peeks > li:hover > div > div {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0)
}

ul.peeks div.title {
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -65px;
}

ul.peeks h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.peeks h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

ul.peeks div.peek {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Wow, so close! The only issue I can see with this is that the boxes do not have a static height and instead are the height of the peek content.

Comment: nope, the only defined height is the titles one, but... it won't change... right?

Comment: Yeah :( The outer box should have a defined height and it potentially can change. Very good ideas for this though.